How to select element but not the same nested element with CSS?
I want to make q element 2em, but only the main parent, not the nested one.


html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
q {
    quotes: "„" "”" "‚" "‘";
    font-size: 2em;
}
<q>One does not simply walk into <q>Mordor</q></q>



Is there a way to do this? I was trying to use q:has(:not(q)) but this only work when there no nested q. Can this be done with a single selector?
I was trying this:
q:has(q), q:has(:not(q)) {
    quotes: "„" "”" "‚" "‘";
    font-size: 2em;
}

But it only works when q is nested, so q:has(:not(q)) is the right solution.
I know that I can use:
q q {
  font-size: inherit;
}

to solve the problem with font-size, but I'm wondering if there is a trick to not have to do this.
Basically, is there a CSS selector that allow to select parent but not children of the same tag?
EDIT: this is not the same question as:
CSS Selector for not a child of element type?
This question is more than 10 years and ask about something totally different.
The linked question is about this scenario:
This should much:
<code>...</code>

this doesn't:
<a><code/></a>

My code is different:
Should much:
<code></code>

Should match parent code.
<code><code/></code>

This is not the same question.

If it's just two levels you need to worry about, q:has(>q) should work

The so called duplicated question is from 10 years ago and don't answer the question. Not to mention that the question is about something totally different.

q:not(q *)  (from the duplicate)
